# PDC not syncing time properly

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntp, time-synchronization

Running 2003 as my PDC and I cannot get the time to sync properly. I've tried to sync with windows and nist with no luck. It does not appear to be blocked by the firewall (verified with `w32tm /stripchart /dataonly /computer:time.windows.com`) and I am not seeing any event log entries. Any ideas why it is not syncing or are there events in the event log I can look for to help me find the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you intend to say that you set this server to hold the PDC emulator role.

You need to start reading here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784800(WS.10).aspx

I would install wireshark to give you some insight to whether the NTP traffic is making the round trip back and forth before "guessing" if your firewall is the problem. The windows event log should tell you whether or not the NTP service is having difficulties making it to the time sources.

Comment: I have verified communication with w32tm /stripchart /dataonly /computer:time.windows.com

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `w32tm.exe /resync` do you get any events in the system log with a source of **W32Time**?  Are you configuring the time source via GPO (Default Domain Controller policy)?

Comment: I get the message "The computer did not resync because no time data was available" in the cmd window. No event log errors.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you have any time sources configured.  What's in your "Default Domain Controller Policy"?

Comment: here are my settings http://imgur.com/Q1ouz.jpg http://imgur.com/fdiBW.jpg

Comment: Anything in "Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Windows Time Service\Time Providers" ???  Specifically, the "NtpServer" setting?

Comment: looks like it should be working: http://imgur.com/1f4Oy.jpg